# Вывести таблицу из MySQL на JSP?

Tags: jsp

Добрый день. Не могу правильно вывести данные в таблицу через .jsp. Данные выводятся, но как-то непонятно, сами данные вверху страницы, а сама таблица ниже, но количество рядов и столбов соответствует количеству данных.

СЕРВЛЕТ

```
  public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {

      public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
          throws ServletException, IOException {

          req.getRequestDispatcher("mypage.jsp").forward(req, resp);
  }
```

JSP

```
   <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>java</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h3>Таблица</h3>
   <%=new java.util.Date()%>
   <br>
        <table border="3">
            <%
                PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
                DaoMyZdorove myZdorove=new DaoMyZdorove();//МОЁ ДАО
                try {

                    List<Article> list = myZdorove.selectAllArticle();
                    for (Article art : list) {
            %>
                <tr>
                    <td> <%pw.println(art.getId()); %> </td>
                    <td> <%pw.println(art.getTitleArticle()); %> </td>
                    <td> <%pw.println(art.getCreatedArticle()); %> </td>
                </tr>
             <%
  }
}catch (DaoException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
             %>
        </table>
 </body>
 </html>
```

выводит вот такое :

[image: вот что выводит в браузере]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужно использовать

```
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
```

На JSP вы должны использовать `<%= %>`

```
<tr>
    <td> <%= art.getId() %> </td>
    <td> <%= art.getTitleArticle() %> </td>
    <td> <%= art.getCreatedArticle() %> </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Спасибо Михаил !! Все заработало !!